# Custom validator is not firing even the textbox is not empty

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

I have a cutomvalidator, textbox.text = 1 and a subroutine:

```
1.
asp:TextBox id="tbxNumber" runat="server" MaxLength="100

2.
asp:CustomValidator id="vNumeric" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbxNumber" Display="None" OnServerValidate="ValidateNumbers2"

3.
Sub ValidateNumbers2(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs)

If Not IsNumeric(args.Value) Then  

  args.IsValid = False

Else

   args.IsValid = True

End If


End Sub
```

When I try to debug vNumeric.Validate, sub ValidateNumbers2 won't fire? Why?

Ideas? I'm wasting my too much time on this little problem. I only have to use customvalidator for some reasons.

Comment: When have you try to dubug that, after you click save button, or you call method in the code by calling vNumeric.Validate() ?

Comment: after the click button event, ValidateNumbers2 won't fire, like nothing happens

Comment: You have already set CauseValidation to true on that button and put breakpoint at the begining of ValidateNumbers2, right ?

Comment: I've already tried, but then nothing happened, I'll try again.

Comment: CauseValidation="True" on Button or Textbox didn't also help.

Answer (score 0):

if the textbox is empty while you're testing, it will not fire. you need to set

```
 ValidateEmptyText="True"
```

in your customvalidator.

Comment: Custom validator is not firing even the textbox IS NOT EMPTY

Comment: Are you working with updatepanels? And you're not working with ValidationGroups?

Comment: Working with updatePanels, but not working with ValidationGroups

Comment: I had sometimes problems with updatepanels. you can try to test it without the updatepanel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed ClientId mode of it, Validators might not supports client Id mode static

[Validators and ClientIDMode issue (ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922574/validators-and-clientidmode-issue-asp-net)

////////////////////

You may try using Force Validation by Page.Validate();

Comment: if i were you, i will try creating a blank test page and add very simple textbox and server validation. if it work, there might be somethink wrong with object setting (i once work with custom validatior in FormView and it not work, i use lable instead as in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880359/does-custom-validator-works-in-formview . if it is still not work, your code might be wrong or it might be some global setting.

Comment: If you are hurry/tired and don't want to waste your time, just use if-else condition and label instead. using javascipt to hide that lable when you change value in textbox. This may imitate the apprearance of validators, though it is not the best way.